# Accessing a tag in an array element of a postgres table with json column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

My Postgres DB Table BookingDetails has columns - id(bigint), info(jsonb)

My Json structure:

```
  "bookingType": “special”,
  “travellers”: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nationality": "SomeValue",
    }
  ],
  “someTag”: “abc”
}
```

The travellers here is an array (and in this example, there’s only one element)

I want to:

1. Select records `where nationality=‘CertainValue’`
2. Update records `set nationality=‘AnotherValue’ where nationality=‘CertainValue’`

I could retrieve the array using:

```
select CAST (info->'travellers' AS TEXT) from BookingDetails
```

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nationality": "SomeValue",
    }
]
```

I could retrieve the array first element using:

```
select CAST (info->'travellers'->>0 AS TEXT) from BookingDetails
```

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "nationality": "SomeValue"
}
```

But how to do a select based on `nationality=‘CertainValue’`?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT jsonb_set(info, array['travellers', (a.id - 1) :: text, 'nationality'], to_jsonb('AnotherValue' :: text))
  FROM BookingDetails
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(info->'travellers') WITH ORDINALITY AS a(content, id)
WHERE a.content->>'nationality' = 'CertainValue'
```

see the [test result in dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BTiAX75s)